# Magento 1.9 Top Links. Issue with removal of addLink from another layout handle

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, toplinks

I have a project where I needed to add a custom link to top.links via XML (This is a product URL). Maybe this is not the correct way to add a product to top.links?  The handle `customer_logged_out` works as expected to add the new desired link, however when I try to remove this link within the handle `catalog_product_view` it does not remove. Below is my content from my `local.xml` file Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <!-- Add Custom Signup link -->
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog">
            <label>Sign Up</label>
            <url>/individual-membership.html</url> <!-- This is a product URL, maybe there is a better way to call the url?  -->
            <title>Sign Up</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>20</position>
            <liParams/>
            <aParams>class="btn btn-primary sign-up"</aParams>
            <beforeText><![CDATA[<span>]]></beforeText>
            <afterText><![CDATA[</span>]]></afterText>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>

<!-- Ideally I'd like to remove by product ID instead of global product view  -->
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <!-- Remove Signup Link from Product Page -->
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
            <url>/individual-membership.html</url> <!-- This does not work -->
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Please note the below `removeLinkByUrl` method below works as expected for a different link.

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <!-- Removes Register link -->
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /></action>
</reference>
```

As requested by the comments below, I've also tried the following without success:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <!-- Remove Signup Link from Product Page -->
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
            <url>/individual-membership</url> <!-- This does not work -->
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>

<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <!-- Remove Signup Link from Product Page -->
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
            <url>individual-membership</url> <!-- This does not work -->
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>

<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <!-- Remove Signup Link from Product Page -->
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
            <url>/individual-membership</url> <!-- This does not work -->
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: Try it by removing '/' from URL

Comment: Also remove that .html

Comment: @gopal, I tried these combinations and these did not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the order Magento combines the XML files and handles. As you probably know magento loops through the XML files and combines them, your local.xml is always at the end.

If you were to look at the complete xml for the page you will see that your layout updates within `catalog_product_view` are higher up than your `customer_logged_out` handle updates.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->getXmlString();
```

So your `removeLinkByUrl` is effectively trying to remove something out of the array that doesn't yet exist.

I know this isn't exactly a solution but an explanation for your problem.

If you were to add the link in the `customer.xml` then the your `local.xml` should have no problem removing it.

Comment: Let me give this a shot...  I started to lean this way, but I never gave it a try.  @nathan

Comment: This does not work either...  I feel I may have multiple problems,  every successful removal by URL has a helper that's called.   Additionally I don't see any of these working with a product.  I don't think this should matter, but I don't use local.xml, I utilize /app/design/etc/theme.xml to define layout overrides.   These typically work exactly like local.xml but more modularized.

Comment: I don't believe this <ur>/individual-membership.html</url> is working as expected in any handle. @nathan, do you have any other ideas?